# What is difference between length of proof and length of its presentation in Peano Arithmetic?

Tags: proof-theory, peano-arithmetic

In this paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397584901117 page $19$ or $29$ it seems to imply there is a difference between length of proof and length of its presentation in Peano Arithmetic.

What exactly does this mean?

Comment: I skimmed through Section 3 of the article, and didn't quite see what you are referring. Can you edit in a page reference in your question, and better yet a quote of the relevant sentences from the article, so it is more easily identifiable?

Comment: sorry corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very roughly speaking:

Suppose I deduce Theorem A from Propositions B, C, and D.

The "length of proof" of Theorem A is

> Length of my proof of Theorem A + length of proof of Proposition B + length of proof of Proposition C + length of Proposition D + lengths of statements of Propositions B, C, and D

The "length of the presentation" is

> Lengths of statements of B, C, and D + MAX(length of proof of A, length of proof of B, length of proof of C, length of proof of D).

---

To put it in a more physical context:

Length of the proof of the "fundamental theorem of calculus" is about 7 or 8 chapters of text, according to most college textbooks.

Length of the presentation of the "fundamental theorem of calculus" is about 3 blackboards (going by most college classroom set-ups).

---

See p29 of the article you linked to, where the concept of "presentation of proof" is defined (in particular you can "erase" things you don't need later.

Comment: let me think a bit.

Comment: why length of presentation is Lengths of statements of B, C, and D + MAX(length of proof of A, length of proof of B, length of proof of C, length of proof of D)? How does this capture the proof? Should length of presentation be at least length of A in this case?

Comment: @Turbo: of course, my rough definition above would be at least length of A (since it is an argument in the MAX function). The length of presentation is computed by: "Write down statement B, prove statement B, erase proof; write down statement C, prove statement C, erase proof; write down statement D, prove statement D, erase proof; write down proof of A using B, C, and D." The maximum space requirement to write all that (with erasure allowed) is obviously what I wrote down above.